# I left an open HTML tag in a Script Editor in Sharepoint. It broke the page and now I can't edit it to fix it.

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

Like the title says, I have a closing script tag as

```
<script>
```

instead of

```
</script>
```

and it broke my Sharepoint site. I cannot edit the page to fix this either; when I click the edit button, nothing happens.

Here is the snippet of code where it breaks:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

...

});
<script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the web part maintenance page by appending `?Contents=1` to the page's URL. From there, you can close or delete the offending web part.

Comment: I added that to the URL but it didn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Whoops, that's because I gave you the wrong parameter (`toolpaneview=2` should open the page in edit mode). Try `contents=1` instead.

Comment: @Thriggle, thank you! This saved me a TON of rework!